# Docker: open container port to all other containers

Tags: docker, containers

I'd like to know how can I open container port to all other containers?

I have three containers, and I want to open some ports to each other. I cannot use `--link` because it's circular link.

I have exposed ports and binded ports to host, but other containers cannot get access to it.

I cannot use docker network either because I'm using Docker 1.8 and I cannot upgrade.
Thanks.

Comment: "other containers cannot get access to it" how did you determine this? Do you get an error message? Did you try with `nc`? Can all containers access a host-service port? Please: share your work, details what you tried and give technical details about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to share a port to linked containers use ...

EXPOSE 8080

in your Dockerfile

WARNING the following ...

```
 docker run -p 8080:8080
```

shares a port from host to container but NOT from container to container

insterestingly

```
docker run -P    (capital P)
```

shares all ports exposed in your Dockerfile to host (as well as other linked cotnainers)

dont forget to do your docker links